# REST API call works in ARC client but not in postman or code

Tags: web-services, rest, web, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST API, which works fine in Advanced REST Client(ARC) but not working in postman and through code.

Weird part is postman throwing 405 error and when accessed through code it throws 400 error code.

The rest api is pinterest pin api : https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins?access_token="token"

Header for request - Content-Type : application/json

I don't think its an issue with Pinterest, because it works fine with ARC client.

Any idea on this issue?

Comment: Try using Fiddler to inspect the raw requests being sent. Compare them to see if there are any differences that may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header and it should work. Not sure why that header creates a problem but once I removed that header it worked for me.

STEPS:

1. I went on [Pinterest API-Explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/)
2. There I've selected Pins -> Return information about a Pin
3. Then I've generated new token and used one Pin ID.
4. Tool generates url that looks like

   https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/368661919478924883/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id

I've used this same URL in Postman, Get Operation and no headers.

Result I get is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "368661919478924883"
  }
}
```

Comment: Removing the header is giving 405 error: Method not allowed.

Comment: How it worked for you? Can you tell me the code you tried?